# AOP practical use of after advice

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj

What is the practical use of After advice in spring AOP, I thought I would use it for cleaning resources but how can I get the handle of those created resources in After advice?

Second thing is what is use of After advice? which cross cutting concern does is addresses?

Comment: logging? logging exceptions? counting successful invocations?

Comment: @JBNizet I am talking about `@After` advice which gets executed no matter what is the outcome of the method

Comment: @JBNizet the ones you mentioned can be addressed using `@AfterReturning` and `@AfterThrows` advice. And if we want to log execution time for a method then thats possible with `@Around` advice.

Comment: release a lock, close a resource opened in a Before advice.

Comment: @JBNizet How can I get the handle for those resources? can you please add an example

Comment: By storing it somewhere in the Before advice. In a ThreadLocal variable for example.

Comment: @JBNizet is it a good Idea to store such things in thread local? cause that method may gets called many times?

Comment: I have no idea of what you're trying to accomplish. You asked a rhetorical question: what could Afetr be used for, how could it get the resource to clean up. I answered that it could be used to clean resources, and that resources could be stored in a thread local. What are you trying to accomplish. Just because After advices exist doesn't mean you must use them.

Comment: @JBNizet I just want to know why do the `After` advice exists after all?  I just don't want to fit them into my application , rather I would like to know the real use case of that concept. Why do designers thought that an After advice is necessary.

Comment: It's not necessary. It's nice to have. You can do everything you want with an Around advice. But having the other kinds of advices allows expressing the intent in a simpler, clearer way and avoiding bugs.